# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}(1-x)^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, uniform-convergence

The given series of function is as follow

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}(1-x)^{2}$$
>   prove that given series is uniformaly convergent on $[0,1]$

**The solution i tried**-The given series form an $G.P$ with  ratio $x \leq1$

i.e

> $$(1-x)^2+x(1-x)^2+x^2(1-x)^2+...$$

Now if i form partial sum of $n$ terms it will be
$$s_n=(1-x)^2 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n=\frac{(1-x)^2}{1-x}$$

after that we get $$s=(1-x)$$

now what can i say about convergence

Because we know that if the series of partial sum is uniform convergence then series is uniform convergence ,but here $s$ is something polynomial type .

Please Help

Comment: I edited the question, thankyou

Comment: You need to show that $\lvert s_n(x) - s(x)\rvert = (1-x)x^n$ tends to $0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$, i.e. for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $n_0$ such that $(1-x)x^n < \varepsilon$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $n \geqslant n_0$. For that, looking where $(1-x)x^n$ attains its maximum is helpful.

Comment: If you happen to already know Dini's theorem, though, that gives you a faster way.

Comment: @DanielFischer i got the value of $x=n/1+n$ but in end after putting this in equation i got the form $\frac{n^n}{n^{n+1}(1/n+1)}$ does it legal to cancel our $n^n$ with $n^n$ as $n $ goes to infity ?

Comment: @DanielFischer i got it ,According to  Dini's theorem here function $(1-x)x^n$ is monotonic and converses to $0$ in $[1,0]$ so this is convergent and the given series of function is convergent .

Comment: Yes, you can simplify the expression inside the $\lim$. But the expression you wrote in the comment isn't quite correct, you forgot an exponent. It's $$\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = \frac{n^n}{n^{n+1}\bigl(\frac{1}{n}+1\bigr)^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{n\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigr)^{n+1}}\,.$$

Comment: I intended to apply Dini's theorem directly to the series. Each term is nonnegative and continuous, so the sequence of partial sums is a monotonic sequence of continuous functions. The pointwise limit $s \colon x \mapsto 1-x$ is continuous, the domain $[0,1]$ is compact, so by Dini's theorem the convergence is uniform. But of course it also works for $s_n(x) - s(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Option:

Weierstrass M test .

$f_n (x)=x^{n-1}(1-x)^2$;

$f_n'(x)=$

$(n-1)x^{n-2}(1-x)^2-2x^{n-1}(1-x)=0;$

$(n-1)(1-x)-2x=0$;

$x(n+1)=n-1$;

$x=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$;

This is the maximum of $f_n$ on $[0,1]$.(Why?)

(Recall : A continuous function on a compact interval attains its maximum, $f_n(x) \ge 0$ on $[0,1]$)

$f_n(\frac{n-1}{n+1})=$

$(\frac{(1-1/n)^{n-1}}{(1+1/n)^{n-1}})(\frac{2}{n+1})^2 <4/n^2.$

Weierstrass M test : $\sum f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct. Other approach would be to show that, since $f$ is continuous and $f(1)=0$ then given $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that for all $x \in (1-\delta, 1],\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: |f(x)|<\varepsilon $.

Now, since $f$ converges uniformly to zero in $[0,1)$ so does in $[0,1-\frac{\delta}{2}]$.

Combining both assertions you get uniform convergence of $f$ in $[0,1]$.